# Can't push initial commit to new github repo from remote repo

Tags: git, github, push, remote-server

I have a website I've been building. It's actually my second attempt. The first time I was able to set up git for version control just fine and use branches for new features. I decided to start the project over however and now git isn't working at all. I've tried to see if it was a permissions thing which is why I can't push my first commit but I don't know if that's the case. HTTPS doesn't resolve my issue either. I created a new rsa key and added it to my github account and that hasn't helped. Running out of ideas. Here's the old cliche error I get:

fatal: 'git@github.com/davidberko/NovayTechnologiesWebsite.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Someone please help lol. I bought a macbook pro and I want to get this website I've built pushed to github so I can clone it on my new machine and continue my development. My old Lenovo with Linux is falling apart. SOS

Comment: You did create a new, empty repository with this name on GitHub, did you? The `push` won't do that part.

Comment: Yeah I did. Still won't work :/

Comment: Use colon instead of forwardward slash in git url.

Answer (score 1):

Did you spell the command correctly ?

Using SSH :

```
git remote add origin  git@github.com:davidberko/NovayTechnologiesWebsite.git
```

Then

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Yeah I set up the remote correctly. I actually changed the line git push -u origin master to git push NovayTechnologiesWebsite master and it worked! Found a helpful stackoverflow question where someone showed another helpless developer (such as myself) how to do it lol. Thanks for the responses everyone

Answer (score 0):

changing git push -u origin master... 
to
git push (project name) origin master 
is the solution. Hopefully anyone else stuck can find this question and answer. Cheers!